Problema al compilar con libpqxx
Al intentar compilar la app de prueba por defecto de libpqxx en Visual Studio 2022 Win10, me detecta unos errores en unas librerías del propio libpqxx:
Lógicamente no he cambiado el código de los archivos que menciona el error pero al revisar lo que veo es precisamente como si la librería intentara utilizar una variable que no está declarada:

Quizá es que no tengo instalada alguna librería básica de C++ en el Visual Studio pero lo dudo porque la instalación la hizo el programa automáticamente y marqué todas las opciones posibles relacionadas con C, C++ y C#.
Actualización:
Dado que los errores parecen ser del Visual Studio al detectar la sintaxis del programa decidí desactivar el IntelliSense y ahora me arrojó otro error de compilación:
'pqxx::operator <<': Do this by hand, probably with better error checking.


En https://tio.run, a partir de la versión 17 de C++ funciona correctamente. Puedes copiar la clase desde el código fuente y comprobarlo. https://github.com/jtv/libpqxx/blob/faf5984448f0dd76a9da93d30cd23e366f059d8a/include/pqxx/zview.hxx

@Mateo estoy compilando con la versión 20, probé con la 17 también y me sigue dando el mismo error, la 14 da aún más errores

Parece ser problem del compilador de microsoft. Lo acabo de probar y tengo el mismo problema. Por lo visto no es capaz de reconocer esa sintaxis. Podrías probar modificando el código de la librería. Tal vez algo de esto te ayude https://github.com/GordonLElliott/Easy-PQXX-Build-for-Windows-Visual-Studio
